# Restart home screen in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application for rooted device. In this application I am editing **launcher.db** file to place shortcuts in some certain positions on the home screen. But to apply changes I need to restart my home screen. How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: Can't you just create an intent and start the activity and call finish() afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, I tested it on a rooted device, and my application was running as a system application:

```
try 
{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "am force-stop com.android.launcher"});
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   //do something
}
```